# Использование GIT

Tags: git

Как лучше всего следить, логический за проектом, есть один проект, иногда в его файлы, вносятся изменения, но они на столько редко или не редко вносятся что уследить за всем нельзя, в итоге прибегают к сравнению файлов (по очереди) либо скачиванием их с FTP и сравниваю с локальной версией.

Вопрос как лучше и проще всего использовать GIT именно с логической точки зрения для одного проекта ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отсутствие контроля версий кода для программного проекта может повлечь за собой неоправданные траты времени и проблемы.

Копировать каждый раз весь проект, вручную описывать версию - **долго и трудоемко**. Мало того, что это будет занимать слишком много места на жестком диске, так еще немудрено запутаться в версиях и использовать, вместо сохраненной правильной версии, промежуточную недоделанную версию с массой ошибок. Хорошо, если потом можно быстро откатиться на правильную версию, но ведь бывают случаи, когда, наводя порядок в архиве, удаляются единственно верные копии с последними наработками.

А теперь ко всему этому еще добавим, что у вас 3-4 разработчика, все находятся далеко друг от друга, у каждого свои архивы и каждый может закачивать свой код основанный на разных версиях!

**Добро пожаловать в настоящий кошмар, где исправленная кем-то ошибка вернется обратно!**

### А как правильно?

Неважно какой у вас проект, как часто вносятся или не вносятся изменения, важно то, что он есть и что потеря кода или нарушение кода - это недопустимый риск.

Поскольку все изменения фактически сохраняются на вашем компьютере, а все изменения GIT на практике только добавляет к репозиторию, очень сложно что-то потерять. Если вы сохранили измененный файл в репозиторий, то его всегда можно будет восстановить к текущему состоянию. А если вы сохранили репозиторий на удаленный сервер командой git push, то вероятность потерять файл стремится к нулю.

Поднимите свой локальный Git сервер (можно даже с веб-интерфейсом, типа gitlab) или используйте сервисы с возможностью приватных репозиториев, закачайте в этот репозиторий весь свой код первичным комитом в ветку master, **исключив с помощью .gitignore все возможные временные файлы и файлы конфигурации**. Если использовать самый простой и распостраненный workflow, то создайте из **master** ветку **development** и туда вносите новые изменения, как только изменения из этой ветки будут протестированы, то мерджите ветку **development** с **master** и отправляете коммит на сервер.

В идеале, можно запретить разработчикам вообще делать комиты в master, а сделать так, чтобы только один человек мог выполнить marge master'а с другой веткой и соответственно выкатить изменения на production сервер.

Далее, как-то нужно заливать это все на сервер. Бывает, что для начала генерируют ключ на веб-сервере, добавляют его как deploy key на сервер с git, потом ставят git на web-сервер, делают clone проекта, и при необходимости изменений просто делают git pull, чтобы получить изменения из ветки выполняя дополнительные действия связанные со сборкой вручную.

Для начала вы конечно можете попробовать так, **но это неправильно**, сборкой должен заниматься сервер сборки (например Jenkins или Gitlab CI), он будет отслеживать наличие изменений в Git, клонировать его, обновлять, выполнять тесты и по успешности сборки закачивать код (деплоить) на работающий сервер.

### Как следить за изменениями

В Git вы сможете с помощью веб-интерфейса или командной строки увидеть: кто, когда, во сколько, с какой целью вносил изменения в файлы и в случае необходимости откатить их. Все изменения в Git должны иметь автора и сообщение.

[Руководство по Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Как раз способос с распространенным workflow мне подходит !